# How to debug a @InvocableMethod

Tags: apex, invocable-method, bots, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I am making a Einstein Bot that call an Apex class. The input is working but the output is empty and i can't understand the reason. I don't see the results of "System.debug()" methods in Developer Console.

How can I see the the results of "System.debug()" methods?

[image: Output empty]

```
public with Sharing class Bot_GetPedido {
    
    public class Input {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public ModelVenda pedidoSelecionado;
    }
    
    public class Output {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public List<ModelVendaFulfillment> fulfillments = new List<ModelVendaFulfillment>();
    }
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='GetFulfillments')
    public static List<Output> getFulfillments(List<Input> inputs) {
        
        List<Output> outputs = new List<Output>();
        
        for (Input input : inputs) {
            
            List<Fulfillment__c> fulfillments = [SELECT Id, Name, Data_Venda__c, Prazo_de_Entrega__c, Status__c FROM Fulfillment__c WHERE Venda__c = :input.pedidoSelecionado.idVenda];
            System.debug('fulfillments = ' + fulfillments);
            
            Output out = new Output();
            
            for (Fulfillment__c fulfillment : fulfillments){
                
                ModelVendaFulfillment mvf = new ModelVendaFulfillment();
                
                mvf.nome = fulfillment.Name;
                mvf.compradoEm = Input.pedidoSelecionado.dataCompra;
                mvf.status = fulfillment.Status__c;
                mvf.PrazoEntrega = fulfillment.Prazo_de_Entrega__c;
                mvf.marca = input.pedidoSelecionado.marca;
                
                out.fulfillments.add(mvf);
                System.debug('SAÍDA = ' + out.fulfillments);
            }
            outputs.add(out);
        }
        return outputs;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Einstein bots, but does switching "Show Debug Level" from Off to On help at all?

Comment: I know nothing of Einstein bots, but are you certain that your `inputs` has something in it?   You might want to add a `System.debug('inputs: ' + inputs);` (or something like it) as soon as you enter `getFullfillments`, before your first `for` loop, just to make sure. | I know that if I don't hold my mouth just right, invocables don't work for me. :^)

Comment: Nicholas Savini, unfortunately, switching "Show debug level" doesn't help, but I appreciate it. I need to see the debugging of the apex class.

Comment: Moonpie, How can I see the the results of "System.debug()" methods? I can't see it in Developer Console.

Comment: I misunderstood when you said that you 'don't see the results of "System.debug()" methods in Developer Console'. I thought you meant that you didn't see debug output that you expected to see; I did not realize you meant that you did not know how to see them at all. Sorry.

Comment: Does this help? From [Einstein Bots Developer Cookbook > Troubleshooting Your Bot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_troubleshooting.htm): "If you didn’t get any insight from the **Events Log**, you can also look into the org’s debug log. From Setup, search for **Debug Logs**. Create a User Trace Flag and specify **Platform Integration** as the **Trace Entity Type**."

Comment: Moonpie. No need to apologize. You wanted to help me. I am grateful that you tried.

Comment: Moonpie, you solved my problem.
I had not done this here specified Platform Integration as the Trace Entity Type. "

I won't be able to see the log on the developer console but I will be able to see it under Setup> Debug Logs.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure whether you can see `System.debug()` statements in the Einstein Bot developer console.  But *Einstein Bots Developer Cookbook > Troubleshooting Your Bot* [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_troubleshooting.htm] states:

> If you didn’t get any insight from the **Events Log**, you can also look into the org’s debug log. From Setup, search for **Debug Logs**. Create a User Trace Flag and specify **Platform Integration** as the **Trace Entity Type**.

You should be able to see `System.debug()` output there.